# django admin list_display invert (not) a boolean field

Tags: django-admin

I have:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'locked', )
```

It displays the nice green and red icons for the `locked` field.

What I want is to show inverted values in `locked` field.

So i wrote this:

```
def not_locked(obj):
    return not obj.locked
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', not_locked,)
```

And this works (inverts the values), but it displays ugly `True` or `False` instead of the nice green and red icons.

How to make it show the icons again?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

just add to your method 'not_locked' attribute boolean=True,

```
def not_locked(self, obj):
    return not obj.locked
not_locked.boolean = True
```